# Showing text for checkboxfor in razorview

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

USING ASP .Net MVC 4 , Razor View

I have a `CheckBoxFor`:

```
    <div class="editor-checkbox-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Is2ndMailBody, new { @name = "secMailBody", @id = "secMailBody", @class = "secMailBody", @onclick = "disable(this.form.secMailBody)", @value = "Create Table", @text = "Create Table" })
    </div>
```

But the CheckBox itself is showing. How can i show a text what the CheckBox for?

my model has :

```
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

javascript is working fine and css also. I just want to know how i can show a text for this checkbox?

**EDIT 1 :**

[image: This is what is showing]

I want the text **Create Second Mail Body** in the right side of the check box.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answer 1: Just put the string right after the CheckBox like below.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody) Create Second Mail Body

    </label>
</div>
```

Answer 2: In Model,

```
[Display(Name = "Create Second Mail Body")]
public bool Is2ndMailBody{ get; set; }
```

In View

```
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody)
</div>
```

Comment: the second answer is better since, clicking on the label change the checkbox value

Answer (score 6):

First add filter to your model that called `DisplayAttribute`

```
[Display(Name = "Some Text")]
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

And you can use Label for model

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Is2ndMailBody)
```

Comment: the value is coming before the checkbox. and it will. I want to show a text "just right side of the checkbox".as we use text/value in aspx files. do i make u understand my problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor
```

instead of

```
@Html.LabelFor
```

in Alizra's answer. This way, .label css style won't be applied to your text.

Comment: With @Html.DisplayNameFor the checkbox doesn't work when you clicking the label.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap you can do this

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody) Create Second Mail Body
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody)
    </label>
</div>
```

example from: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

In your model class use Data Annotations to give a display name to the property

You need to have this using statement on top of the model class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Then set the Display Name attribute

```
[Display(Name = "Create second mail body")]
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

After that in your view use wrap the checkbox with the following div tag. You will need to have bootstrap CSS referenced in the view if it's not

```
<div class="checkbox">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Is2ndMailBody, new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="editor-checkbox-field">
<label> Create Second Mail Body @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Is2ndMailBody, new { @name = "secMailBody", @id = "secMailBody", @class = "secMailBody", @onclick = "disable(this.form.secMailBody)", @value = "Create Table", @text = "Create Table" }) </label>
</div>
```

That is:

```
    <label> Your text @HTML.checkBoxFor() </label>
```